anyone used android-target-instructions and added a skip button to skip remaining steps
I'm trying to implement android-target-instructions library and I want to skip when user click on a skip button in the library it says .finish() to skip but nothing happened anyone can help ?
the library i'm talking about for reference
https://github.com/Kyash/android-target-instructions?tab=readme-ov-file#customize-simpletarget-layout
private fun showInstructions() {
        val userCredentials = CommonUtilities.getUserTokenAndName(requireActivity())
        val sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(requireActivity())
        if (!userCredentials.first.isNullOrEmpty()
            && !userCredentials.second.isNullOrEmpty()
//            && CommonUtilities.isHomeFirstTimeOpening(requireActivity())
        ) {
            val target1 = SimpleTarget.Builder(requireActivity())
                .setTarget(binding.oscarChiefIc)
                .setTitle("Floating Action Button")
                .setHighlightRadius(100f) // Circle shape
                .setDescription("Discover culinary inspirations - click to explore recipes and ingredients.")
                .setMessageLayoutResId(R.layout.instruction_layout) // This is custom layout
                .build()
            val target2 = SimpleTarget.Builder(requireActivity())
                .setTarget(binding.scanIcon)
                .setTitle("Floating Action Button")
                .setMessageLayoutResId(R.layout.instruction_layout) // This is custom layout
                .setHighlightRadius(100f) // Circle shape
                .setDescription("Scan all your products and add it to your cart.")
                .build()

            val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(requireContext())
            val popupView: View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_message_view, null)

            val width = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
            val height = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
            val focusable = false
            val popupWindow = PopupWindow(popupView, width, height, focusable)
            val skipBtn = popupView.findViewById<Button>(R.id.skipBtn)
         
            val targets = arrayListOf(target1, target2)

            view?.post {
                popupWindow.showAtLocation(view, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0)
            }
            skipBtn.setOnClickListener {
                popupWindow.dismiss()
                parentFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.container_frameLayout, NewHomeFragment()).addToBackStack(null).commit()
            }
            TargetInstructions.with(requireActivity())
                .setTargets(targets)
                .start()
        }
        sharedPrefs.edit().putBoolean(HOME_FIRST_RUN, false).apply()
    }

I tried to make it reload the fragment but the problem that the steps still found because it has to be dismissed when clicking on it

here's an idea it might work with you If you are not able to finish it.
try to create two fragment one showing the instructions and the other is not
the showing instruction will open the one without instructions in two cases:
1- when user press skip button
2- when user already opened the app once (shared preferences will help to do checks)
the fragment without instructions will contain all your app logic
here's another solution:
try to use  requireActivity().recreate() when and skipButton.setOnClickListener{}
try the best solution that's fits your code
I found library you can use instead of android-target-instructions called SpotLight
https://github.com/TakuSemba/Spotlight
